# Save screen shot of div to facebook

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a game site. I would like when a high score is achieved that a screenshot or image of the page shown is shown as the thumbnail for a facebook share. 
I have gotten the share button to work but how do I show a screenshot of the div to share? I don't have to save the image I just want it to be shown in the facebook share thumbnail.

I added this to the div i would like to show.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftruthsandlie.com%2Frandom%2F%3FCategory%3DHarryPotter&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

and the facebook code to the header of the page.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=932190710260559";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Copied from the facebook page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

This works fine. But it just uses a random image. Any ideas of how to achieve the thumbnail i need? I am using wordpress.

site: https://truthsandlie.com/random/?Category=HarryPotter. I would like the share button in the popup div to save as the thumbnail.

Comment: The `og:image` meta tag (which goes in your HTML `<head>`) is the one responsible for choosing which image Facebook pulls in, but your overall request is far more complicated and would require server-side image generation (or many images made manually on your end) and custom share URLs that alter the og:image meta tag. Either way, here's the relevant information on og:image: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Comment: SO it is not possible to save the div as an image and display using og:image?

Comment: It's not completely impossible, but very complicated. You'd have to screenshot a section of the page in JavaScript (which is very tricky), save the image somewhere on your server, and create a unique share URL for that user, which populates the `og:image` meta tag with the unique image.

Comment: ok so i would repopulate the og:image with new image URL from the screenshot. Doesn't sound too hard. But I don't know how to get the screenshot

Comment: I have added an og:image and it is not working

Comment: Your `og:image` tag is above the ones automatically added by WordPress (you can see this if you View Source). Needs to be lower in the `head`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131294/discussion-between-dario-and-jon-uleis).

Comment: Don't change the og:image for the same URL constantly, that is just asking for trouble. Use the Feed dialog or publish via API - both ways allow you to specify the thumbnail image URL to be used at runtime.

Comment: I have seen this before you cannot share a blob ,createobjecturl or anything that is local to user's machine.If you try it would throw some error related to url not recognized or something